# "message": "No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI while sending the POST request for backup in APIM

Tags: azure, azure-storage, backup, azure-api-management, azure-rest-api

Using this Azure Management [REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-disaster-recovery-backup-restore?tabs=rest#back-up-an-api-management-service) for backing up the APIM Instance data but getting the below error:

`"message": "No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI`

[image]

Passed the Authorization token and the backup parameters in the body correctly but not sure what is the cause of this error.
The APIM Instance has plenty of APIs with the GET, POST, PUT, DEL Operations.

Comment: I guess there's an error in the url

Comment: `https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/<subscriptionId>/resourceGroups/AKSClusterProd/providers/Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/prod-us-gateway/backup?api-version=2022-08-010` - This is the format of URL I have used

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your guess.

You're wright! The URL is mistaken while using in Postman.
And then If I send the request again with the correct URL, I got the below message:

```json
 "code": "ServiceLocked",
        "message": "The API Service assist-prod-us-ni25-gateway is transitioning at this time. Please try the request again later.
```

After sometime, I got the backup file in the given Storage account container area.

[image]