# Unable to open/decode the backup file of Azure APIM got using REST API

Tags: azure, postman, azure-blob-storage, backup, azure-api-management

Continue to previous Question: ["message": "No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI while sending the POST request for backup in APIM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76593711/)

[image]

This is block blob type and unable to read the content inside the file as content-type is given the value of `application/json` in the headers.

[image]